# Mediawiki include page views to each article

Tags: mediawiki, mediawiki-extensions

I am looking for a way to include statistics of the page views for each article. Similar to the Wikipedia, but no need for such an advanced approach.
Any suggestion/recommendations, since it was officially removed from MW?

Comment: It was moved into [an extension](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:HitCounters).

Comment: Extension:HitCounters: "Currently it is only possible to migrate wikis using MW 1.25 to use this extension. A fresh install in MW 1.26 and higher is not possible! " :(

Answer (score 0):

This Extension says it's in beta but may still meet what you're looking for?

I see that you're using a MW 1.26? This extension works with 1.22+

https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:UserPageViewTracker

There are a bunch of other extensions that may meet your needs. Every Extension page shows which version of Mediawiki it is able to work with, and whether or not it is a stable release or still in production.

You may also want to check out this thread in stackoverflow:

[How to use Wikipedia API to get the page view statistics of a particular page in wikipedia?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5323589/how-to-use-wikipedia-api-to-get-the-page-view-statistics-of-a-particular-page-in)